# Display data from XLSX to datatable

Tags: javascript, json, datatables, xlsx

I am trying here to display some data from an Excel file into a DataTable.
In the console I have this error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference

Anyone know how to do it properly?

```
$('#input-excel').change(function(e){
            alert('test');
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                        var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
                        var sheet_name_list = wb.SheetNames;

                        var dataj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {raw: true, defval:null})
                        table = $('table.test').DataTable( );

                        dataj.map(function(r) {
                   table.row.add(JSON.stringify(r)).draw().node();      

                        });    
                }
        });
```

Comment: I suggest reviewing [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). `table` does not have a property named `row`. [It has a *function* named `row()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row\(\))...

Comment: row.add()

Add a new row to the table.

Comment: Can you post your complete code here ?

Comment: You can check this implementation https://github.com/imdurgeshpal/Read-Excel-file-and-display-in-HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to display properly data in DataTable

```
$.each(dataj, function(i, item) {


                  table.fnAddData([

                          item.Name,
                          item.CIN


                   ]);
```